# How to get the selected dates from jquery datepicker, full year calender to array for saving to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

```
<li class="demo full-row">
    <h3>Full year</h3>
    <div id="full-year" class="box"></div>
        <div class="code-box">
        <h4>Code used</h4>
        <pre class="code prettyprint">

        var today = new Date();
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
        numberOfMonths: [3,4],
        defaultDate: '1/1/'+y
        });</pre>
    </div>
</li>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

function myFunction() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("full-year").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Currently i'm getting one value on clicking "Try it" button. ie, if i selected 3 dates and clicked "Try it" button, it is displaying last selected date only. I want whole selected dates for saving it into database. The requirement is to save list of holidays into database.

Comment: have you try `var x = $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker('getDates');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `var x = $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker('getDates');` , this will return  the array of dates associated with the multiDatesPicker in the specified format: "string" (default) for localized string format, or "object" for javascript date object format.

Reference : [Multiple Dates Picker Documentation](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/)

Answer (score 0):

Try that the operator `+=` which keep the current value and add something after - [More infos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("full-year").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + ','; 
}
```

Remember to remove the last `,` before sending the data :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
```